# Console.WriteLine() vs Enviroment.NewLine

Tags: vb.net, console-application

As a new programmer in Visual Basic today I came across the `Enviroment.NewLine` function. I am writing a **console application** in Vb.net and I was wondering what's the different between `Enviroment.NewLine` and `Console.WriteLine()`.

Visually, the only thing I can see is both produce a new line in the console window. Just `Enviroment.NewLine` seems to be a more cleaner method in the code?

Here is some sample code for `Enviroment.NewLine`:

```
'Welcome message
 Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this program.. " & Environment.NewLine)
'Ask to enter first number
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first number: ")
```

Here is some sample code for `Console.WriteLine()`:

```
'Welcome message
 Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this program.. ")
 Console.WriteLine()
'Ask to enter first number
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first number: ")
```

Both do exactly the same thing as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) is a property that returns a `String`, it's not a method. And you can compare [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) even less with it. That method prints a given string on the console and adds the  current line terminator. That's comparing apples to oranges.

If i want to  print a string to a console and plan to add other strings on the next lines i use `Console.WriteLine`. The method is self-explaining.
If i want to create a string that contains the line terminator i concat `Environment.NewLine`.

The most important is readability.

Comment: So which would be best if you just wanted to leave a blank line?

Comment: Havent you read the answers? Environment.Newline outputs nothing, it's just a constant. How could it produce an empty line? It's a bit like asking if you should use the webclient for downloading something or an integer.

Comment: @igrimpe, If you tried yourself, It does produce a blank line in the console.

Comment: @Tahmid: no, it doesn't print to the console. That's what Console.WriteLine does. The Environment.NewLine just contains the characters that would be interpreted as a line break in the Console(not only there). Console.WriteLine appends them implicitly as opposed to Console.Write.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look up the code for `Console.WriteLine()` but I imagine it looks like:

```
public Shared Sub WriteLine(Format as String, Args)
   Write(Format, Args)
   Write(Environment.NewLine)
End Sub
```

Environment.NewLine is not a function, it is a ReadOnly Property. It's main purpose is to become platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine is a method of the Console class that writes the argument passed to the console and ADD an Environment.Newline at the end of the output. (While Console.Write doesn't append that constant)

Enviroment.NewLine is a `constant property` representing the newline for the current environment.

So, you use the Console.Writeline to output your text to the console and automatically add a newline and carriage return. If you append an Enviroment.NewLine to the Console method you end up with two newlines in your output console.

The Environment.NewLine constant is useful for other purpose, for example when you need to append a newline constant in the output of a text file (Although the StreamWriter has its own method to write a line with a newline terminator like the console)

Comment: Which would be best if you just wanted to leave a blank line?

Comment: If you want to print a blank line after the first line output I would prefer the two calls to the `Console.WriteLine` method. It is more explicit about your intentions and doesn't require a string concatenation. But it is really a minimal difference.